Workflow Validation Failed Error: The function cannot be called from a logic app. It must not have a custom route
I'm getting the following error when saving my Logic App workflow which calls a function app
Workflow validation failed for the workflow ''. {"error":{"code":"InvalidFunctionRoute","message":"The function '/subscriptions/{subid}/resourceGroups/{myresourcegroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{nameoffunction}/functions/myfunctionapp' cannot be called from a logic app. It must not have a custom route."}}

Both my function app and logic app are in the same resource group.
The function app is a python .py file with code:
print("Hello World!")

How do i debug this error?


Does it have custom route in it? like .../myfunction/app like this?

@RithwikBojja where do i go to check this?

Can you provide your Function URL, ill check it. Or you can check it in Function app -> thn click on function-> then click on get func url

it looks like https://{nameoffunc}-{randomstring}.australiaeast-{number}.azurewebsites.net/api/{myfunctionapp}?code={hash}

So,  function with custom routes cannot be called with that connector. Here code = hash, this is custom route

You cannot call a function with custom route with that connector. You can use a HTTP Action as below:

To get function URL:
Open Function :

You can select anyone of below:

This way you can call function app with custom routes.
Output:

